# Should we Migrate applications in order to host on SOA platform?

Tags: soa, esb

I have a question related to Integration Design. We're adopting the SOA using JBoss Fuse Service Works suite. Now it's raising a big question: When we develop a new service/application,

1. Should we host it on the Fuse Service Works and develop it based on SwitchYard specifically? This decision leads to all business logic will be put on SwitchYard
   [image]
2. Alternatively, we develop a new service/application based on the independence platform(it could be any open source framework that could expose REST, SOAP services). This decision leads to the service has its own business logic.
   [image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to always remember when using an ESB is that the ESB is an integration server not an application server. The ESB is there to facilitate communications between various applications. If you build an application in the ESB the ESB is now bound to that application, in short ESB's are not supposed to house business logic.

A ESB is designed to do the following:

- Monitor and control routing of message exchange between services
- Resolve contention between communicating service components
- Control  deployment and versioning of services
- Marshal use of redundant services
- Cater for commodity services like event handling, data transformation and mapping, message and event queuing and sequencing,   security or exception handling, protocol conversion and enforcing proper quality of communication service

The part that confuses people is that an ESB can  "host" business logic but it is not the appropriate place. Let me explain. Most businesses have several software packages such as CRM, Client database and marketing database. The CRM can have a SOAP interface for search for a person, the client database might require an SQL query and the marketing database might have a REST interface for example.All these systems and their interfaces are called providers/producers.

If I wanted to created an enterprise wide search for a person record will require a search tool to interface with all the provider interfaces).This is where the ESB makes the most sense.

In this scenario one approach could be to design a SOAP web service that is used to do a enterprise wide search. You would create a new service which has the operations and data structures required to do search with but you will not expose the provider interfaces directly. Always use abstraction on the ESB. The new service will map its operations and data structures to the provider data structures.

So you will have one service that can call the three interfaces. The biggest advantage of doing things like this is that when you for example upgrade the customer database to use REST services you can then change the mapping from the enterprise wide service to the customer database interface without changing the other services.

Think about it this way. When you expose abstracted services on the ESB that does not tie your data consumers into a specific provider you can change thr provider in the back end and redo the mapping. You consumers will not be affected.

One such a real world example is when Bank have different banking back end but they use the IFX protocol to communicate with each other. It does not matter if the data provider is a credit card machine, atm or SAP banking module. They all speak IFX.

So in your case go for option two. Let the applications host the business logic and the ESB host the integration.

Hope this helps a bit.